# Is there an "easy" way to create stratified split of frames using h2o.ai?

Tags: h2o, subsampling

Stratified sampling is old, and very significant.

- Donald Knuth (high priest of computer science) uses it for evaluating the work of his PhD students, and for teaching his deeply and sincerely held religious beliefs. ([link](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/things.html))
- Royal Society article from 1934 on the topic. ([link](http://static.stevereads.com/papers_to_read/on_the_two_different_aspects_of_the_representative_method.pdf))

In the r-interface to h2o.ai they have a method to split frames "h2o.splitframe".  Is there a way to make a stratified split along the distinct elements of another column?

Here are R packages that do not do this in h2o:

- https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fifer/versions/1.0/topics/stratified

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to apply stratified sampling before model training since h2o.ai provides different types of **fold_assigment** parameter including "Stratified". It applies "Stratified" sampling during training so you only need to set ***fold_assingment*** and ***fold_column*** parameters. 
You can find the details in the link below.
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/fold_assignment.html?highlight=stratified#example